# Java Spring ApplicationEventPublisher between sessions

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm fairly new to Spring and I recently came across this ApplicationEventPublisher, but can't make it work the way I want..
I have a session bean that registers the EventListener as follow:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class SessionBean implements Serializable {

  @Async
  @EventListener
  public void handleObjectPersistedEvent(ObjectPersistedEvent event) {
    Utils.LOG.debug(user.getFirstName() + ": ObjectPersistedEvent " + event.getObject());
  }

  private User user;
```

While my dao autowires the ApplicationEventPublisher like this:

```
  @Autowired
  private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

  public void persist(User user) {
    entityManager.persist(user);
    publisher.publishEvent(new ObjectPersistedEvent(user.getId()));
  }
```

The dao.persist is called by a service that is called by a controller when a form is submitted.
My idea is that when an admin user does a change to another user, a message is broadcasted to tell all sessions that hold a reference to this second user to update.
The problem is that the session of the admin user that does the change is the only one that receives the message.
How can I make this message go to all session beans? Is is possible or am I onto the wrong solution?
Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of session scope? To isolate session beans, so every user has their own version of session-sensitive beans?

Comment: Yes, but I thought that ApplicationEventPublisher could help me send messages to other parts of my application even if not in the same session. I guess I was misguided by its name. Could you think any other solution to solve my problem?

Comment: I'll need to ask you some more questions before posting an answer. First, it seems you try to use session to achieve 2-way communication (so "logged" users are notified when there's a change to the system)? If so, even if you could notiy other sessions this approach will not work. You need bidirectional channel. Probably websockets is the way to go.

Comment: It wouldn't be two way, sessions don't notify back. Websockets are not a solution either because I'm trying to refresh the object in the session bean, I don't have to communicate anything to the frontend. Looking again at the problem I think I got the setup wrong. I should keep these objects in a singleton and have the session beans access it in a controlled way. This way I would also avoid every session to keep a duplicate of the object.

Comment: Ok, so how do you want to handle your event? In your example I see log only, but that's just a placeholder.